# How to refresh chart data and axes from server response in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

I have a bar chart that needs to be re-rendered after the user selects what data to display. Not only does the data in the chart need to be refreshed, but the x and y axes and legend need to be re-generated based on what data comes back.

Currently I'm assigning the new data and x and y axes and legend to the chart when the json comes back from the server (in probably a very hacky way). However, the chart never refreshes the data in the view.

Here is my code:

```
var rows = [];
var columns = [];
var legendFields = [];

var formSelection = null;

Ext.define('ColumnChartStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    fields: Fields(),
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory'
    }
});

function Fields(columns) {
    var fields = [];

    if(columns){
        for(var name in columns[0]) {
            fields.push(name);
        }

        return fields;
    }

}

Ext.define('Project.view.reports.BuildToBuildReport', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'buildToBuildReport',
    autoScroll: true,
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    items: [
        {

            xtype:'tagfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Software Build(s)',
            width: 700,
            store: {
                type: 'softwareBuilds'
            },
            //allowBlank: false,
            name: 'softwareBuildIds',
            tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                '<ul class="x-list-plain"><tpl for=".">',
                '<li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item">{generation} - {build}</li>',
                '</tpl></ul>'
            ),
            labelTpl: '{generation} - {build}',
            valueField: 'buildId',
            allowBlank: false
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [{
                xtype:'tagfield',
                margin: '0 0 20 0',
                width: 700,
                fieldLabel: 'Metric Type(s)',
                store: {
                    type: 'metricTypes'
                },
                tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                    '<ul class="x-list-plain"><tpl for=".">',
                    '<li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item">{metricName} ({abbreviation})</li>',
                    '</tpl></ul>'
                ),
                labelTpl: '{metricName}',
                valueField: 'metricTypeId',
                allowBlank: false,
                name: 'metricTypeIds'
            },
                {
                    margin: '0 0 20 5',
                    text: 'Show Report',
                    xtype: 'button',
                    handler: function() {

                        var form = this.up('form'); // get the form panel

                        var formValues = form.getValues();

                        var formData = {
                            'metricTypeIds': formValues.metricTypeIds,
                            'softwareBuildIds': formValues.softwareBuildIds
                        };

                        //if (form.isValid()) { // make sure the form contains valid data before submitting
                            //console.log(form);
                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                url: 'api/reports/buildToBuild',
                                method:'POST',
                                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                                params : Ext.JSON.encode(formData), //, gridRef.getValues()
                                success: function(response) {

                                    rows = [];
                                    columns = [];
                                    legendFields = [];

                                    var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText, true);


                                    if(data.metrics){
                                        var metrics = data.metrics;
                                        var entries = data.entries;

                                        for(var i=0; i<metrics.length; i++){
                                            var row = {};

                                            row.abbreviation = metrics[i].abbreviation;

                                            var dataNumber = 0;

                                            for(var j=0; j<entries.length; j++) {

                                                if(entries[j].metricIndex === i){

                                                    var dataName = 'data' + dataNumber;

                                                    row[dataName] = entries[j].value;
                                                    dataNumber++;

                                                }

                                            }

                                            columns.push(row);

                                        }

                                    }

                                    var softwareBuilds = data.softwareBuilds;

                                    for(var k=0; k<softwareBuilds.length; k++){
                                        legendFields.push(softwareBuilds[k].generation + ' - ' + softwareBuilds[k].build);
                                    }


                                    var chart = form.down('cartesian');
                                    var chartStore = chart.getStore();


                                    chartStore.data = columns;
                                    var fieldNames = Fields(columns);
                                    chartStore.fields = fieldNames;


                                    var axesField1 = fieldNames[0];
                                    var axesField2 = [];

                                    for(var f=1; f<fieldNames.length; f++){
                                        axesField2.push(fieldNames[f]);
                                    }


                                    var axesFieldLeft = [];
                                    axesFieldLeft.push(axesField2[0]);

                                    chart.axes[0]._fields = axesFieldLeft;

                                    chart.axes[1]._fields = [axesField1];

                                    chart.series[0]._xField = axesField1;

                                    chart.series[0]._yField = axesField2;

                                    chart.series[0]._title = legendFields;


                                },
                                failure: function(form, action) {

                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Submission failed', 'There was an error.', action.result);
                                }
                            });
                        //} else { // display error alert if the data is invalid
                        //    Ext.Msg.alert('Submit Failed', 'Please make sure you have made selections for each required field.')
                        //}
                    }

                }
            ]

        },
        {
            xtype: 'column-stacked',
            controller: 'column-stacked',

            items: [{
                xtype: 'cartesian',
                reference: 'chart',

                width: '100%',
                height: 460,

                store: Ext.create('ColumnChartStore'),

                legend: {
                    docked: 'right',
                    border: 0,
                    tpl: [
                        '<tpl for=".">',
                        '<div class="myLegendItem" style="margin:5px;padding:0px;cursor:pointer;">',
                        '<div class="" style="float:left;margin:5px;width:10px;height: 10px; background:{mark};opacity:.6"></div><div style="float:left;">{name}</div>',
                        '<br>',
                        '</div>',
                        '</tpl>'
                    ],
                    itemSelector: '.myLegendItem'
                },
                interactions: {
                    type: 'itemhighlight',
                    tooltip: {
                        renderer: 'onEditTipRender'
                    }
                },
                insetPadding: {
                    top: 40,
                    left: 40,
                    right: 40,
                    bottom: 40
                },

                axes: [{
                    type: 'numeric',
                    position: 'left',
                    adjustByMajorUnit: true,
                    grid: true,
                    fields: ['data1'],
                    renderer: 'onAxisLabelRender',
                    minimum: 0
                }, {
                    type: 'category',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    grid: true,
                    fields: ['month'],
                    label: {
                        rotate: {
                            degrees: -45
                        }
                    }
                }],
                series: [{
                    type: 'bar',
                    title: legendFields,
                    xField: 'month',
                    yField: [ 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4' ],
                    stacked: false,
                    style: {
                        opacity: 0.80
                    },
                    highlight: {
                        fillStyle: 'yellow'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        renderer: 'onBarTipRender'
                    }
                }]
            }],

            tbar: [

                {
                    xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
                    width: 200,
                    defaults: { ui: 'default-toolbar' },
                    items: [
                        {
                            text: 'Stack'
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Group',
                            pressed: true
                        }
                    ],
                    listeners: {
                        toggle: 'onStackGroupToggle'
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Preview',
                    handler: 'onPreview'
                }
            ]
        }]

});
```

Maybe I need listeners on the individual chart elements that need to be refreshed?

Comment: The chart will update automatically with the store it is bound to. You are creating a new store for it each time it is called with
                store: Ext.create('ColumnChartStore')
Just use store: 'ColumnChartStore'

Comment: You're right Jesse. I refreshed the data in the store and the chart re-rendered automatically. The only thing it didn't re-render was the series titles.